How were luminous intensity changes for each EM frequency measured in the blackbody experiments of the late 19th c., which led to up to Planck’s Law?
If in today’s parlance it would be either ‘spectral density’ or ‘spectral radiance’ that was in fact measured then as opposed to ‘luminous intensity’ please feel free to clarify.
Kindly note that my main motivation/curiosity for this inquiry is that there were highly historically important measurements taken with high precision for magnitude of the luminosity/radiance of emission streams of various frequencies of electromagnetic radiation (as a result of temperature changes) which led to the formulation of equations that expressed Planck’s constant for the first time. And thus of course that experimental measuring could not have been defined by Planck’s constant beforehand for those precise measurements to be taken…yet digging in online seems to always link back to measurement techniques pre-assuming the constancy of this specific number. So, very curious on how those blackbody radiation experimental measurements were taken/determined back then over 120 years ago, since they led to the defining of one of the most ubiquitous constants of modern scientific definitions (two, if you include the Boltzmann constant) :)
Links to papers (if in English/translated) where those experiments are detailed back at the time of them, would be helpful.
